# What is the single best reason - specific to Christianity - that the Christian God is the real God?

Tags: faith, apologetics, comparative-religion

Looking at history it seems clear that we are a God inventing species and obviously 99.99% of these Gods cannot be real. But let us suppose that there is indeed a Higher Being.

What is the best *specifically Christian* reason one could give that the Christian God is the real one, i.e. *one which could not be given by other religious people* (so e.g. "I personally feel that He is real" or "It says so in the Bible" would not qualify because people of all kinds of religions say comparable things).

Thank you

Comment: **Best** reason? You're sure to get a lot of answers there. You should narrow your criteria so this very good question doesn't get flag-crippled for being opinion based.

Comment: @LCIII: Thank you. Yes, I thought about that but I think "one which could not be given by other religious people" is a pretty tough criterion already. Or do you see any good possibility of making it more concrete?

Comment: This is a great question and I would love to brainstorm this and see answers, but I know the community here well enough to tell you that this will likely not get reopened in pretty much any form. The question is basically, "According to Christians, why is Christianity believable, but only give reasons exclusive to Christianity?" I think it is a fair question, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Jesus is Risen**

All of Christianity rests on the resurrection of Jesus from the dead.  If He is indeed risen, then He is indeed the Christ, the Son of God.  From this, it follows that the Christian God is, in fact, the true God.

Paul affirmed this in his opening statement to the Romans:

> Paul, a bond-servant of Christ Jesus, called as an apostle, set apart for the gospel of God, 2 which He promised beforehand through His prophets in the holy Scriptures, 3 concerning His Son, who was born of a descendant of David according to the flesh, 4 **who was declared the Son of God with power by the resurrection from the dead**, according to the Spirit of holiness, Jesus Christ our Lord.  Romans 1:1-4 NASB

The resurrection of Jesus from the dead powerfully declares that He is the Son of God, the Christ, and our Lord.

What flows from this is forgiveness, redemption, belonging, victory over death, victory over sin, and a host of other things.

Everything else--fulfilled prophecy, miracles, answered prayer, transformed lives--is powerful, but secondary to the resurrection of Jesus.

If Jesus is not risen, Christianity would not exist.
If Jesus is risen, Christianity is true.

Comment: +1: I think this is indeed the best reason one could give. You could add 1 Corinthians 15:14

Comment: Christianity exists because *people believe that* Jesus is risen. If your argument is that "Christianity is true because only the risen christ could start the religion" then you are breaking the scope of the question. Most religions start with an alleged remarkable event. And then people do believe it. So, many religions claim, "This religion is true because it started with this event and would not have started unless the event were true." Islam and Mohammad's visions are a prime example. The Muslim claims that the religion could not have started without the prophet's visions.

Comment: @fredsbend A vision that one person has is hardly comparable to the resurrection of the dead witnessed by over 500 people.  The historicity of the resurrection is the critical element of Christianity.

Comment: @Narnian I understand the arguments for *why the event is true*. That's somewhat irrelevant to the question. The point is that your answer breaches the scope of the question because other religions make the same argument that their religion started with an event and the event must be true or the religion would not have started. All events have a measure of historicity from complete fact to complete non-fact. This is your argument: Christianity exists, therefore Jesus is risen, therefore, Christianity is true.

Comment: Basically, "Christianity's existence is unique enough." It's circular reasoning and is common among other religions.

Comment: @Narnian: This is interesting! Non-Christian religious books often only just write something like "many people saw this and that miraculous event", they don't provide names nor testimonies, so you can't really take this seriously. You are implying that the resurrection is different, please give me the sources who those 500+ were and what they said. Thank you :-)

Comment: @Narnian: OK, I think you are referring to 1 Corinthians 15:6, right? But this one sentence can't be all, this would be a really weak argument. I am sure that there must be more information on these 500+ people somewhere? Please help.

Comment: @vonjd The argument *against* the claim is that there is no record outside the Bible of a person claiming that they themselves actually saw the resurrected Jesus. The only mention of this massive witness number is the NT.